# Set focusable and focusableInTouchMode property to false from Kotlin code

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to set focussable and focussableInTouchMode property of a Button to true/false from Kotlin code.

Actually in Kotlin following :

```
stb_help_btn.focusable = false
```

Gives error :

```
The Boolean literal does not conform to the expected type Int
```

Can sombody please help in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [View](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) source code, `setFocusable()` is method overloading with 2 signatures:

```
/**
 * Set whether this view can receive the focus.
 * <p>
 * Setting this to false will also ensure that this view is not focusable
 * in touch mode.
 *
 * @param focusable If true, this view can receive the focus.
 *
 * @see #setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)
 * @see #setFocusable(int)
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#View_focusable
 */
public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
    setFocusable(focusable ? FOCUSABLE : NOT_FOCUSABLE);
}

/**
 * Sets whether this view can receive focus.
 * <p>
 * Setting this to {@link #FOCUSABLE_AUTO} tells the framework to determine focusability
 * automatically based on the view's interactivity. This is the default.
 * <p>
 * Setting this to NOT_FOCUSABLE will ensure that this view is also not focusable
 * in touch mode.
 *
 * @param focusable One of {@link #NOT_FOCUSABLE}, {@link #FOCUSABLE},
 *                  or {@link #FOCUSABLE_AUTO}.
 * @see #setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#View_focusable
 */
public void setFocusable(@Focusable int focusable) {
    if ((focusable & (FOCUSABLE_AUTO | FOCUSABLE)) == 0) {
        setFlags(0, FOCUSABLE_IN_TOUCH_MODE);
    }
    setFlags(focusable, FOCUSABLE_MASK);
}
```

From Kotlin to call:

`setFocusable(boolean focusable)`: using `isFocusable` property

`setFocusable(@Focusable int focusable)`: using `focusable` property

**Root cause:** You call `focusable` and pass a boolean as param, that why the compiler gave the error.

**Solution:** Combine two method overloading together

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    stb_help_btn.isFocusable = false
} else {
    stb_help_btn.focusable = View.NOT_FOCUSABLE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If(button.hasFocus) {
button.setFocusable(false);
button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}
```

**Update:**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
button.focusable = View.NOT_FOCUSABLE
button.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
```

Requires API `Oreo` and higher for `focusable`

Comment: Actually in Kotlin following :
stb_help_btn.focusable = false

Gives error : The Boolean literal does not conform to the expected type Int.

Comment: I have answered to what your question is asking for. Update your question or ask a new question.